# How to position the renderer issue in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an error as

[Error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lbvk.png)

It shows a lot of renderers issues in the console, but I still cannot locate where the error widget or layout is, it looks does not reveal the wrong widget directly. Is there any tool to find the issue quickly?

Comment: The error points to SingleChildScrollView. You likely have that inside a Row, Stack, etc. without using a flexible parent.